# lost data when convert Bson file to Json file

Tags: mongodb

I used the mongodb dump command to dump a collection to a Bson file as following:

```
mongodump --quiet -d mytestDB -c testCol -o /tmp
```

the size of output bson file is **24GB**, and then I used **bsondump** to convert the Bson file to a Json file as following: `bsondump testCol.bson > testCol.json.`

But the testCol.json file only **23GB**, I think it should much bigger than the bson file. So is the bsondump corrupted some where, but I didn't see any error message.
When I check the count of json file by using: `wc -l testCol.json.` it much less than the real db collection count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the testCol.json file only 23GB, I think it should much bigger than the bson file.

No, that sounds about right. In fact, I'm surprised it's only 5% smaller.

BSON is *not* a space-efficient format. It's actually rather wasteful -- in particular, it represents strings with a type code, a 32-bit length *and* a null terminator, so there are six bytes of overhead for every string present in a BSON document, as compared to the two used in JSON (the opening and closing `"`).

The difference in line count is not unexpected. Line breaks have no specific meaning in JSON -- they're typically escaped as `\n` in strings -- so the line count of a JSON file doesn't have any particular meaning.

Comment: Okay, but I still have problem. When I enter MongoDB command line and issue: db.testCol.count(), there were 350Million records, but when I count the Json file: wc -l testCol.json, there only 38Million. I'm very confused about this.